# Sort entries by global variable category

Tags: structure, globals, sorting, plugin-supersort

I'm picking a season category (spring, summer, fall, winter)  in a global variable that should dictate what entries come to the top of non-season category pages. These entries are already on a category page, sorted by their main category. I need extra sorting to showcase the "Spring" entries, for instance. Something like this:

**Without the season global variable chosen**

1. Test post 1 (Summer)
2. Test post 2 (Spring)
3. Test post 3 (Spring)
4. Test post 4 (Winter)
5. Test post 5 (Winter)

**With the global variable "Spring" chosen**

1. Test post 2 (Spring)
2. Test post 3 (Spring)
3. Test post 1 (Summer)
4. Test post 4 (Winter)
5. Test post 5 (Winter)

Basically, I want to bring the entries that are using the chosen Global Variable Category to the top, the remaining entries can be sorted by postDate descending. These entries are in a Structure btw, if that matters.

Structure = 'generalContent'
Category Field = 'season'
Global Variable = 'season.season'

Simplified code of my category page.

```
{% paginate craft.entries.section('generalContent').relatedTo(category).order('lft desc') as entries %}
  {% for entry in entries %}
    {{ entry.title }}<br>
  {% endfor %}
{% endpaginate %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to retrieve the entry ids for the season entries and all entries separately; subtract the 'season entry ids' from 'all entry ids' (using craft's `without` twig filter); then merge the two arrays back together (using twig's `merge` filter) in the proper order. You can then use this new id array to generate an elementCriteriaModel which can be used in your `paginate` expression.

```
{% cache %}
    {% set season = season.season.first() %}
    {% set seasonEntryIds = craft.entries.section('generalContent').relatedTo(season).order('lft desc').ids() %}
    {% set allEntryIds = craft.entries.section('generalContent').order('lft desc').ids() %}
    {% set nonSeasonEntryIds = allEntryIds|without(seasonEntryIds) %}
    {% set sortedEntryIds = seasonEntryIds|merge(nonSeasonEntryIds) %}

    {% paginate craft.entries.id(sortedEntryIds).fixedOrder(true) as entries %}
        {% for entry in entries %}
            {{ entry.title }}<br>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endpaginate %}
{% endcache %}
```

Since there are a lot of queries happening here, it might also be a good idea to wrap the code in 'cache' tag.

Comment: Douglas, everything looks great up until the sortedEntryIds. For whatever reason, it's putting them back in order in Structure's native Ascending order.

Comment: Also, not sure if this is a hit to performance, but `nonSeasonEntryIds` doesn't appear to be needed. The merge filter already overrides existing keys in the array. I get the same result with this: `sortedEntryIds = seasonEntryIds|merge(allEntryIds)`

Comment: Patrick Harrington (mildlygeeky on Slack) gave me the heads up that the parameter `.fixedOrder(true)` should be used on the `{% paginate %}` element. Douglas, if you want to put that in your answer, I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: Using `merge` and `without` does not create any additional database queries on their own, so shouldn't be any hit to performance either way. I am surprised, however, to hear that the merge filter is overriding existing array items, as we are simply dealing with an array of numbers – and there are many reasons why you might want duplicate numbers in your array. I presume this is because, as you say, there is an underlying key there somewhere  — I'll watch out for that. Regarding `fixedOrder(true)` — great catch —I updated the answer. Regardless — I'm glad you got it working.